# Terraform interpolation to json file when json requires value to be integer

Tags: terraform

Trying to work out if this is possible or not. Trawled terraform docs to no avail (not much surprise there).

Take the below extremely slim line example.

```
[
  {
    "cpu": "${var.master_container_cpu}",
  }
]
```

Adjoined to this tf parameter when invoking `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource;

```
container_definitions = "${file("task-definitions/example.json")}"
```

Will result in the following error;

```
Error: aws_ecs_task_definition.example-task: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ContainerDefinition.Cpu of type int64
```

any help more than welcome :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you should use a [template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) to compile the JSON before using in the definition

```
data "template_file" "task" {
  template = "${file("${task-definitions/example.json")}"

  vars {
    cpu = "${var.master_container_cpu}"
  }
}
```

In the JSON file you can reference the var using `${cpu}`

Then you are able to use the output as your definition

`container_definitions = "${data.template_file.task.rendered}"`

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this. I did test it and it does work though, so thumbs up :)

Comment: Just wanted to provide an update in 2021 that for Terraform version 0.12 and above, there's need to use interpolation syntax for non-constant expressions. So for example, `"${file("${task-definitions/example.json")}"` should be written as `file("${task-definitions/example.json")`. While the old syntax still works, it is deprecated.

Comment: should be replaced by built-in templatefile() now